# Insert Image on Excel using Open XML

Tags: excel, openxml

I am using [this](http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Creating%20an%20Excel%20spreadsheet%20from%20scratch&referringTitle=Home) toolkit to write Excel.Every thing is fine with this,

but i am not getting **how can i inset image and put style** on some rows on my excel

i am using c#

Comment: See this duplicate post

[C# & OpenXML: Insert an image into an excel document][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793950/c-sharp-openxml-insert-an-image-into-an-excel-document

Answer (score 0):

I am using EPPlus for this specific task. It's a really nice and stable library.

[EPPLus - Advanced Excel 2007 spreadsheets](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)

And you may find allot of samples, including adding images and cell formatting, [here](http://zeeshanumardotnet.blogspot.gr/2011/06/creating-reports-in-excel-2007-using.html)