# XML SDK 2.0 - Images - Excel file

Tags: openxml-sdk

With the use of the Open XML SDK 2.0, I did preformed the Reflected Code of an Excel file.
Along with other things, the Excel file has some images in some of the cells. When I run the code that was generated, the file show the images just fine.

What I need to do is to programatically inject images in place of the 
images that are there now. The thing is, I cannot find where the images are at in the code that was generated.  How can I figure this out? Also what is the easiest way to replace those images with new ones programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to take a look at a similar question about inserting images into Excel files with OpenXML SDK: [C# & OpenXML: Insert an image into an excel document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793950/c-sharp-openxml-insert-an-image-into-an-excel-document).

Basically, those files are created as separate document *parts*. The answer I linked to should show You how to insert a new image into a document, however, in order to substitute existing images with your custom ones, you could probably just modify the binary data of appropriate `ImagePart` (and some other associated properties).

If You need some help with the code performing this task, let me know.