# How to add image on the top while exporting to excel in DataTable?

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, openxml, export-to-excel

I have a report to export in excel. Everything is working fine but I cannot export the image `MyImage.jpg` ? How can I add the iamge to column so that the report looks like `https://www.screencast.com/t/xxVdQjLmL5G`. My only issue is that i cannot export the image. How Can I do this?

My Code in DataTable is :

```
public IActionResult WorkOrderExportToExcel([FromBody] WorkOrderViewModel model)
       {

           var uploadPath = string.Format("uploads\\" + CurrentUserDetails.SellerID + "\\Excel\\");
           var targetDirectory = Path.Combine(_iconfiguration["BManageFolder"], uploadPath);

           if (!Directory.Exists(targetDirectory))
           {
               Directory.CreateDirectory(targetDirectory);
           }

           var filename = "workOrderReport" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().Replace('/', '_') + ".xlsx";
           var savePath = Path.Combine(targetDirectory, filename);
           var loadURL = _iconfiguration["BManageUrl"] + uploadPath + filename;
           DataTable MissingSingedDocumentList = ReportService.ExportWorkOrderExcel(model);
           DataTable dtt = new DataTable();

           dtt.Columns.Add("POSTING ORDER : INSTRUCTIONS & CONFIRMATION OF RECEIPT OF MATERIALS");

           dtt.Columns.Add(" ");
           dtt.Columns.Add("  ");
           dtt.Columns.Add("   ");
           dtt.Columns.Add("    ");
           dtt.Columns.Add("     ");
           dtt.Columns.Add("      ");
           dtt.Columns.Add("       ");
           dtt.Rows.Add("Date : " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
           dtt.Rows.Add("From : " + model.Name);
           dtt.Rows.Add("Email : " + model.Email);
           dtt.Rows.Add("To : " + model.productionVendorOne + "  " + model.productionVendorTwo);
           dtt.Rows.Add("RE : " + model.JobName);
           dtt.Rows.Add(" ");
           dtt.Rows.Add("Market",/*,"Posting Date"*/model.OrderType + " Date","Unit #", "Media Owner", "Media Type", "Size", "Design", "Date Materials Received");
           DataRow[] rows = MissingSingedDocumentList.Select();
           foreach (DataRow dr in rows)
           {
               dtt.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
           }
           dtt.Rows.Add("");


           DataSet ds = new DataSet();
           dtt.TableName = "Work Order Report";
           ds.Tables.Add(dtt);


           ExcelHelper.AppendMultipleSheetWhileDoingExportToExcel(ds, savePath);

           return Ok(loadURL);
       }
```

My AppendMultipleSheetWhileDoingExportToExcel function is

```
using (var workbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(Savepath, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
{
    var workbookPart = workbook.AddWorkbookPart();
    workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();
    workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets = new Sheets();

    //declare our MergeCells here
    MergeCells mergeCells = null;

    foreach (DataRow dsrow in table.Rows)
    {
        int innerColIndex = 0;
        rowIndex++;
        Row newRow = new Row();
        foreach (String col in columns)
        {
            Stylesheet stylesheet1 = new Stylesheet();
            Cell cell = new Cell();
            cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
            cell.CellValue = new CellValue(dsrow[col].ToString());
            cell.CellReference = excelColumnNames[innerColIndex] + rowIndex.ToString();

            if (table.TableName == "Work Order Report")
            {
                string cellNameWorkOrder = dsrow[col].ToString();
                if (cellNameWorkOrder == "POSTER: 10% MUST HAVE APPROACH AND CLOSE-UP SHOTS - PHOTO OF EACH CREATIVE" || cellNameWorkOrder == "BULLETINS: 100% CLOSE-UP AND APPROACH OF EACH UNIT")
                {
                    if (mergeCells == null)
                        mergeCells = new MergeCells();

                    var cellAddress = cell.CellReference;
                    var cellAddressTwo = "I" + rowIndex.ToString();
                    mergeCells.Append(new MergeCell() { Reference = new StringValue(cellAddress + ":" + cellAddressTwo) });
                }
            }

            newRow.AppendChild(cell);
            innerColIndex++;
        }

        sheetData.AppendChild(newRow);
    }
    //add the mergeCells to the worksheet if we have any
    if (mergeCells != null)
        sheetPart.Worksheet.InsertAfter(mergeCells, sheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First());
}
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793950/c-sharp-openxml-insert-an-image-into-an-excel-document

Comment: Thank You Very Much , It took a bit time but it worked !!!!!