# Inserting images inside excel cells using C# with the OpenXML 3.0.1.0 library

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

I am working on a project in C# language using OpenXML 3.0.1.0 library and I need to insert inside dynamically generated excel files at runtine, rows containing cells that have as value an image.

Searching the internet I was able to find some solutions that allowed me to succeed in generating a file and inserting the images within an excel file by placing it at a cell but not inside it.

Below is a snippet of code from the solution I am currently using which works similarly to the solution proposed in the first answer of the question you can find at [C# & OpenXML: Insert an image into an excel document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793950/c-sharp-openxml-insert-an-image-into-an-excel-document):

```
 var drawingsPart = worksheetPart.DrawingsPart;
 if (drawingsPart == null)
     drawingsPart = worksheetPart.AddNewPart<DrawingsPart>();

 if (!worksheetPart.Worksheet.ChildElements.OfType<Drawing>().Any())
 {
     worksheetPart.Worksheet.Append(new Drawing { Id = worksheetPart.GetIdOfPart(drawingsPart) });
 }

 if (drawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing == null)
 {
     drawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing = new WorksheetDrawing();
 }

 var worksheetDrawing = drawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing;

 ImageFormatManager ifm = Configuration.Default.ImageFormatsManager;
 IImageFormat format = ifm.FindFormatByFileExtension(ext);
 var imagePart = drawingsPart.AddImagePart(GetImagePartTypeByBitmap(format.Name));

 using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
 {
     image.Save(stream, format);
     stream.ToArray();

     MemoryStream imageMemStream = new();
     stream.Position = 0;
     stream.CopyTo(imageMemStream);
     stream.Position = 0;

     imagePart.FeedData(stream);
     Bitmap bm = new(imageMemStream);
     A.Extents extents = new();
     var extentsCx = (long)bm.Width * (long)((float)914400 / bm.HorizontalResolution);
     var extentsCy = (long)bm.Height * (long)((float)914400 / bm.VerticalResolution);
     bm.Dispose();

     var colOffset = 0;
     var rowOffset = 0;

     var nvps = worksheetDrawing.Descendants<NonVisualDrawingProperties>();
     var nvpId = nvps.Count() > 0
         ? (UInt32Value)worksheetDrawing.Descendants<NonVisualDrawingProperties>().Max(p => p.Id.Value) + 1
         : 1U;

     var oneCellAnchor = new OneCellAnchor(
         new xdr.FromMarker
         {
             ColumnId = new ColumnId((colNumber).ToString()),
             RowId = new RowId((rowNumber).ToString()),
             ColumnOffset = new ColumnOffset(colOffset.ToString()),
             RowOffset = new RowOffset(rowOffset.ToString())
         },
         new Extent { Cx = extentsCx, Cy = extentsCy },
         new xdr.Picture(
             new NonVisualPictureProperties(
                 new NonVisualDrawingProperties { Id = nvpId, Name = "Picture " + nvpId, Description = imgNamespace },
                 new NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties(new A.PictureLocks { NoChangeAspect = true })
             ),
             new BlipFill(
                 new A.Blip { Embed = drawingsPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart), CompressionState = A.BlipCompressionValues.Print },
                 new A.Stretch(new A.FillRectangle())
             ),
             new ShapeProperties(
                 new A.Transform2D(
                     new A.Offset { X = 0, Y = 0 },
                     new A.Extents { Cx = extentsCx, Cy = extentsCy }
                 ),
                 new A.PresetGeometry { Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle }
             )
         ),
         new ClientData()
     );

     worksheetDrawing.Append(oneCellAnchor);
 }
```

What I get, however, is visible in this image below:

[image: Result]

While what I want to obtain is something like this:

[image: Desired result]

I then went to unzip the xlsx file from which I got the image of the result I would like to get, and from what I could understand the association between image and cell is done taramite of metadata, but neither in the official documentation of the library, nor elsewhere could I find how it is possible to do this.

Can anyone suggest how I can do this?

Comment: Those two images aren't similar. The first one contains text and a single image of a watch band. While the second image contains two images that don't appear anywhere in the first image and no text. It's not clear how the _Result_ relates to the _Desired Result_.

Comment: `inserting the images within an excel file by placing it at a cell but not inside it` - that's what you get in Excel. Images do not go inside cells. You can make it look like they do by resizing the rows and columns so that they match the image size.

Comment: To make the above comment a bit clearer: Excel is pretending that the image fits inside a cell. You are going to have to do the same thing if you want the same effect - i.e. write code to mimic what Excel does.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. 

Unfortunately, however, what you wrote is not useful for me to obtain the result I need.

To better clarify what I intend to achieve, below is a link to the official Excel documentation which explains how to manually do what I would need to do programmatically:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/insert-picture-in-cell-in-excel-e9317aee-4294-49a3-875c-9dd95845bab0

Comment: I too would like to do this. I know it's possible because my installed Excel client 365 can do it. Using code I could only mock it using OneCellAnchor and shrinking the image.